# Switch to realname from username

Tags: web-app

I'm the only backend developer for a Drupal site and we seldom encounter technical difficulties. The last one was with an AJAX call and to resolve that, I suggested we switch to realname from username; and he rejected it, claiming that might affect the site badly. How true is that? We have 100~ users.

Comment: On average, how frequently do your users login (daily, weekly)? How long have they been using this Drupal system (weeks, months, years)? Requiring them to login with their real name rather than username  would most likely break the convention that they use on most other sites they frequently access.

Comment: No  no, I meant switching to registering with realname.

Comment: Ok. If you switched to real name, would existing users still login with their username, or would they have to use real name moving forward? Would new users never need to create a username/login with username?

Comment: Old users with username, new ones with realname

Comment: Im curious as to what problem usernames have with AJAX that realnames could fix, I feel like there must be a better solution.

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49542/usernames-vs-real-names

Comment: @DasBeasto because there were problems with checking if the username exists in the database, with AJAX.

Comment: @TolgaÖ. Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @jazZRo I'm working with Drupal, and I'd deen doing some coding to check   with AJAX if a given username exists in the database, and show some warning if it does. But for some reason, Javascript stopped running so I suggested that we switch to realname registering instead of username.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who commented. I ended up injecting the same javascript which had stopped working, to the page.